# How to change date format in the toolbox of a Google Visualization timeline

Tags: javascript, date, google-visualization

I'm creating a timeline with Google virtualization.  This works great. My only problem is the date displayed inside a toolbox that will show once you hover a bar.

The date format is stuck at Month-Year. 
As I looked into the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformatter) , I found the dateformat function. This is exactly what i needed. I tried to implement it in my code but just seems to ignore it.

Here is my javascript so far: ([Or live version here](http://koenhendriks.com/chart/))

```
var container = document.getElementById('example1');
var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'Title'
});
dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'Status'
});
dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'Start'
});
dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'End'
});
dataTable.addRows([
    ["1", "Planning", new Date(2013, 5, 20), new Date(2013, 6, 21)],
    ["2", "Design", new Date(2013, 6, 25), new Date(2013, 7, 25)],
    ["3", "Development", new Date(2013, 7, 25), new Date(2013, 10, 11)],
    ["4", "Implementation", new Date(2013, 10, 15), new Date(2013, 11, 14)],
    ["5", "Testing", new Date(2013, 11, 18), new Date(2013, 12, 10)],
    ["6", "Delivering", new Date(2013, 12, 1), new Date(2013, 12, 21)]
]);

var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    formatType: 'medium'
});

formatter.format(dataTable, 2);
formatter.format(dataTable, 3);

var options = {
    timeline: {
        showRowLabels: false,
        barLabelStyle: {
            fontSize: 10
        },
        groupByRowLabel: false,
        colorByRowLabel: false
    },
    avoidOverlappingGridLines: false,
    colors: ['#556270', '#4ECDC4', '#C7F464', '#FF6B6B', '#C44D58', '#A7A7A7']
};

chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

As you can see i try to format the Start and End date to a 'medium' format. But when the chart is drawn i still just see the Month-Year format.

How can i make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Timeline charts don't use the formatted values of the dates, and they don't expose any formatting options.  I suggest making a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support.